# Floating Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a footer I am making for a webpage that looks like this[image]

As you can see the right column will not stay in line with the others and the spacing between them is not even. The gradient behind each column is a picture. I tried using pull-right but when I go to resize then it looks weird and doesn't stack on top of each other. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="gradient left">
        <div class="text-center button-center">
        <a class="btn btn-danger " href="http://nhgreatlakes.com/Portals/Merit/tabid/1298/Default.aspx">
        <i class="fa fa-external-link fa-lg"></i> LAUNCH NEW HORIZONS<br>PORTAL</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gradient text-center center">
        <div class="vertical-center">
        <h4 id="connect">Connect With Us!</h4>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/meritnetwork"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/meritnetwork"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="http://merit.edu/contact/"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a></div>
</div>

    <div class="gradient text-center right">

        <h3 id="ML">Click to view our upcoming events</h3>
        <a href="http://merit.edu/learning/"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x" ></i></a></div>

</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.gradient{
    width: 278px; 
    height: 106px;   
    background-image: url('gradient.png');

}
.button-center{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);   
}

.vertical-center{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.left{
    float: left;
}

.center{
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto; 

}
.right{
    float: right; 
}
```

I need each section to be evenly spaced and to stack correctly when it's resized. And the footer spans the whole container FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within the `<div class = 'row'>` can add the `<div class = "col-sm-4 '>` as shown in the [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) of bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='background: #55D946'>a</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='background: #5333EC'>b</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='background: #D8F02F'>c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes them in the same row but it does not span the entire column. Meaning there are just three boxes are towards the left. I need one on the left, one in the center, and one on the right.

Comment: but you can used the class pull-right of bootstrap pull-left and text-center

Comment: For some reason using pull-right makes the last col go into the next row. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Yes, I either get something that looks like this: http://prntscr.com/58owzy or this http://prntscr.com/58oxai I think my problem is I need spaces between my divs not touching how yours are in that picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65397/discussion-between-diego-cardenas-and-mia).

Answer (score 0):

Since your using bootstrap you can use columns in your row, i have added this to your code. Look at how the boostrap grid system works for further understanding.

see [Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/tocmsx4u/)

```css
.gradient {
  width: 278px;
  height: 106px;
  background-image: url('gradient.png');
}
.button-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.center {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.right {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4  gradient left">
    <div class="text-center button-center">
      <a class="btn btn-danger " href="http://nhgreatlakes.com/Portals/Merit/tabid/1298/Default.aspx">
        <i class="fa fa-external-link fa-lg"></i> LAUNCH NEW HORIZONS
        <br>PORTAL</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4  gradient text-center center">
    <div class="vertical-center">
      <h4 id="connect">Connect With Us!</h4>

      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/meritnetwork"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/meritnetwork"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="http://merit.edu/contact/"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 gradient text-center right">

    <h3 id="ML">Click to view our upcoming events</h3>
    <a href="http://merit.edu/learning/"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x" ></i></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know with bootstrap you get a 12 grids running across.

You need something like: 
div class = row for container .

```
div class= col-md-4  // for all 3 boxes. This assumes no margins or padding on divs otherwise change 4 to a 3
```